# Install VirtualBox on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, installation

I'm trying to install VirtualBox 5.2 on Windows 10. I downloaded the file here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads, but when I run it, all I get is the following screen:

[image: VirtualBox installation screen]

When I click `Run`, the installation apparently ends with no further information.

After a few minutes, a dialog box opens that says "Installer is no longer responding":

[image: Installer is no longer responding]

Comment: You need to verify that the Windows Installer service is actually running.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help guys! It turned out I forgot to do the most important step on Windows before doing anything else: **reboot the machine**!

Comment: It is very likely the Windows Installer service wasn't in a functional state, based on my research, on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the installer.  Choose "Properties".  If there, in the lower-right check the "un-block" box and apply the change.  Right-click the installer, choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Thanks, but now it just silently fails. "Unblock" just skips the screenshot I posted.

Comment: Can you run any other program that requires elevated permissions?  Some other installer?  If so then there might be a problem with that installer and if not then it would point to a settings issue on your local machine.

Comment: Never mind, saw your answer where you said rebooting resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to launch by holding shift key + click with right mouse click and choose run as admin
2. Check if your bitness is wrong (32 bit for 32 bit machines / 64 for 64)
3. Is there anything the event viewer shows?

Comment: I did try Run as Administrator. I got an extra box saying "Do you want this program to make changes to your computer". Still no installation. There is only one installer. My computer should be able to run both 32 and 64-bit programs.

Comment: The only event I can see related to the installation is a security audit, which passes every time. Can you suggest a specific place I should look?

Comment: If the installer was a 64-bit application, the application wouldn't even run, and Windows would indicate it was a 64-bit application.  The installer also is clearly a 32-bit application, based on the filename, there also isn't 64-bit versions of VirtualBox anyways.